# laravel list of Applications if last status is closed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Last Status Closed Applications

User
table 1: applications

| id(pk) | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | naveed |

table 2: statuses

| id(pk) | status | application_id(fk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pending | 1 |
| 2 | submitted | 1 |
| 3 | closed | 1 |
| 4 | observation | 1 |

now i want to get list of applications if last status is closed.
only add this application in list which last status is closed.
note: this application not added into list which have at least one status closed.

The given blow code is wrong.

```
$applicationsWithClosedStatus = Application::whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'closed');
})->get();
```

another wrong

```
public function status() {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::class)->latest ();
    }
$applicationsWithLastClosedStatus = Application::whereHas('status', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'closed');
})->get();
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a list of applications where the last status is "closed" and exclude applications with at least one status as "closed?"

Comment: Instead of `hasOne(...)->latest();`, I think you need to use `hasOne(...)->latestOfMany();`, which would return a single-model relationship to your `Status` Model, based on `created_at`, which then _should_ work with `->whereHas('status', function ($query){ return $query->where('status', 'closed'); });` (Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the latestOfMany, achieving perfect results. By obtaining the last status, I can now determine whether it is closed or not.

```
public function applicationStatus(): HasOne
{
$this->hasOne(ApplicationStatus::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
\DB::select("select id from applications where id in (select application_id from (select max(id), application_id from statuses where status="closed" group by application_id) AS t1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

gets data if the last status is **closed**

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM statuses as s
INNER JOIN applications as a on a.id = s.application_id
WHERE s.id IN (  
  SELECT MAX(s.id) as max_id
  FROM statuses as s 
  GROUP BY s.application_id
) AND s.status = 'closed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve it as follows:
In the model like a ApplicationModel that extends the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model have a function like yours as status.
But like this

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ......\Status;

....

public function status(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Status::class);
}
```

Now you can use like so:

```
use ......\Application;

...

public function getApplicationWithStatus()
{
    $application = new Application();
    $result = $application::with('status')
      ->where('status', 'closed')
      ->get();

    return $result !== null ? $result : false;
}
```

Now in the result should be the expected result.
Hope it helped.